# How to test an AngularJS watch using debounce function with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a controller with a watch that uses debounce from lodash to delay filtering a list by 500ms.

```
$scope.$watch('filter.keywords', _.debounce(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.filtered = _.where(list, filter);
  });
}, 500));
```

I am trying to write a Jasmine test that simulates entering filter keywords that are not found followed by keywords that are found.

My initial attempt was to use $digest after assigning a new value to keywords, which I assume didn't work because of the debounce.

```
it('should filter list by reference', function () {
  expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
  scope.filter.keywords = 'rubbish';
  scope.$digest();
  expect(scope.filtered).not.toContain(item);
  scope.filter.keywords = 'test';
  scope.$digest();
  expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
});
```

So I tried using $timeout, but that doesn't work either.

```
it('should filter list by reference', function () {
  expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
  $timeout(function() {
    scope.filter.keywords = 'rubbish';
  });
  $timeout.flush();
  expect(scope.filtered).not.toContain(item);
  $timeout(function() {
    scope.filter.keywords = 'test';
  });
  $timeout.flush();
  expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
});
```

I have also tried giving $timeout a value greater than the 500ms set on debounce.

How have others solved this problem?

**EDIT: I've found a solution which was to wrap the expectation in a $timeout function then call $apply on the scope.**

```
it('should filter list by reference', function () {
  expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
  scope.filter.keywords = 'rubbish';
  $timeout(function() {
    expect(scope.filtered).not.toContain(item);
  });
  scope.$apply();
  scope.filter.keywords = 'test';
  $timeout(function() {
    expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
  });
  scope.$apply();
});
```

**I'm still interested to know whether this approach is best though.**

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad approach. You should use an angular-specific debounce such as [this](https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce/blob/master/angular-debounce.js) that uses $timeout instead of setTimeout. That way, you can do

```
  $timeout.flush();
  expect(scope.filtered).toContain(item);
```

and the spec will pass as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    ...
    spyOn(_, 'debounce').and.callFake(function (fn) {
        return function () {
            //stack the function (fn) code out of the current thread execution
            //this would prevent $apply to be invoked inside the $digest
            $timeout(fn);
        };            
    });
});

function digest() {
    //let the $watch be invoked
    scope.$digest();
    //now run the debounced function
    $timeout.flush();
}

it('the test', function() {
    scope.filter.keywords = ...;
    digest();
    expect(...);
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Using the spyOn to replace the _.debounce, check this link. http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=Jasmine+test+does+not+see+AngularJS+module